# Insulating solid walls, permeable membrane vs solid insulation

Tags: drywall, insulation, vapor-barrier, basement-refinishing, basement-insulation

I've got an integral garage being converted to living space (bedroom).

Around half the longest  wall and rear wall is below ground which is insulated and well drained from the outside. Front wall above ground (orig. doorway).

The solid walls are 200mm concrete and rendered (inside a garage standard), no experience of damp.

Ideally I wanted to use a rigid foam insulation fastened and sealed to the solid wall, but that doesn't seem to be a popular option in this country.

So, I'm proposing to treat the solid wall much like a cladding. i.e.

1. Perimeter seal a permeable wind barrier against the inside of the solid wall (facing out). This should stop potential damp in the wall coming into contact with the framing.
2. Followed by 100mm of timber battens and fiberglass insulation (in two 50mm lots in opposite directions to make running services easier).
3. Finish with drywall (and possibly a vapour barrier behind the drywall).

Can anyone see any potential downsides to this construction?
Cheers

Comment: Sounds good. I prefer an impermeable felt layer than spread-on, or paint-on, barrier, whch can fail with the concrete.

Comment: Is putting the barrier layers on the outside of the mass wall not an option?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I wish it was possible to go on the outside, but the garage is part of the foundation cast concrete walls and there is a timber framed house on top. Putting it outside would take the wall out past the cladding on the main house.

It's possible of course, but it would look a pigs ear :-)

Comment: @r13 I assume if you put an impermeable layer next to the concrete, then you'd definitely omit the vapour barrier behind the drywall?

Comment: p.s. @ThreePhaseEel The outside of the concrete wall is rendered and painted. Below ground is plastic bubble sheet, insulation and drains/gravel etc. No history of damp.

Comment: Any barrier needs to be directly in contact with the previous material and before the stud and drywall. I don't see you need a vapor barrier, it is for the slab=on-grade application.

Comment: Depending on climate you might end up with a dew point at the concrete, preventable by a VB at drywall but which risks trapping moisture. In this case (if it applies to you), the solution would be high-R VB e.g. XPS against the concrete, then batt, and then no VB. Why is this "not popular"?

Comment: @P2000 all data I can find shows at least 2/3rds of the insulation on the outside. 
But the technical know-how is incomplete, even SINTEF this countries national building research people have 'stopped advising' folks on insulating basements because they've had too many failures. 

GLAVA the local fiberglass manufacturers, are recommending no more than 5cm of insulation on the inside. And this is up against the concrete with a membrane behind any studs fastened to the wall. I'm not happy to have fiberglass up against the concrete...